# Writing Django Unit Tests for Views

Tags: django, django-testing

Does anyone have a good tute/example of writing good tests for views? Most of the stuff I've been finding was from mid 2008 which is only a little helpful.

Comment: I've just finished Karen M. Tracey's book on testing + debugging Django - it is excellent, and covers all of this. https://www.packtpub.com/django-1-1-testing-and-debugging/book

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alex Gaynor wrote some tips about this very subject just the other day:

[Getting started with testing in Django](http://lazypython.blogspot.com/2009/11/getting-started-with-testing-in-django.html)

Comment: You should have copied some info from the blog in the answer. Link 404s now which leaves this answer incomplete and not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but I've been looking into this same topic and found this example test code very helpful.

http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/tip/registration/tests/views.py

Comment: Thanks! This one I have found to be useful as well http://www.displayofpatience.net/2009/02/test-driving-django-application-development/

Comment: @RoryHart  that link returns a 404.  Update link is here http://www.displayofpatience.net/blog/2009/02/test-driving-django-application-development/

Comment: Though the link seems like a potential solution, please add some context around the link so users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Also quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.